# Javascript function only called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a function which should be called on every iteration, however it looks like it is only called once and then not at all afterwards.

I can't see, but there must be something in this code block; the function that should be called is `draw()`:

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    dataset.length = 0;
    var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    //console.log(distances);

    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        if (buffer[i][0] == distances.miles) {
            buffer[i][1][0]++;
        }
        //console.log(buffer);
        dataset.push(buffer[i][1][0]);
        //console.log(dataset);  
        draw();
    }


}
```

I know the function `draw()` works and that it's getting the correct updated data from dataset array, as that is sent to the function `draw()`.

Comment: draw() isnt even called in the loop

Answer (score 5):

`draw()` is outside your loop, move it up two lines :)

Comment: Thanks I've moved it up into the for loop but still exactly the same problem

Comment: Are you sure its the same problem? To debug, put a log statement in draw and see how many times it is executed

Comment: Also, check what buffer.length is, needs to be more than one !

Comment: Putting the console.log(dataset) at the beginning of the function shows updated values each iteration.

Comment: So its now working as expected? If not try logging the dataset within the draw() method to see if it gets the same data

Comment: Both are getting the same data values updated correctly, but still no chart drawn after the first iteration.

Comment: draw() is fine, because if I don't reset the array it plots the graph BUT with all the elements in dataset not just the updated values.